# To make a variable or column name an object in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark with scala, is there any easy way to automatically turn the variable or column into an object from imported data and therefore we can use `column_a.contains("something")` per se inside .map( )?

Comment: I can't work out what you're actually asking here. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are coming from R. Spark is row oriented and not column oriented. If you want to do a `contains` for example you would first `filter` the rows and than `apply` a map to it, or use `collect` and do both operations at once but this is a bit harder to get right.